# Whois Queries on a port besides 43

Tags: networking, proxy, whois

How would one use whois via a proxy server behind a corporate proxy using a port beside 43.

Problem: I want to whois a domain / ip

Why Can I not do this:

1) Firewall allows 21/tcp, 22/tcp, 23/tcp, 119/tcp, 389/tcp, 554/tcp, 636/tcp, 2401/tcp, 7070/tcp , ICMP traceroute, ping

1) and http. Http goes through a corporate proxy though and I don't know what it does ...

How can I whois then?

I'm thinking via a whois proxy (e.g. http://www.ip-adress.com/proxy_list/190.225.246.147:80)

Thanks

Comment: Why not simply specify the whois proxy host name and port number to the whois client?

Comment: I'm reasonably sure that's the port # to use on the host not the port I send it from.

Comment: Whichever whois proxy or server that is behind the firewall, its port number must be allowed to pass through by the firewall. If the whois server isn't 43, the proxy must be able to use custom port number to access a whois server. HTTP proxy can only be used for HTTP protocol, but HTTPS proxy can be used as a tunnel of any protocol (layered protocol). Using HTTPS proxy to access a whois server would require a whois client that support HTTPS proxy. i.e.: mainly use whois protocol, but also use HTTPS protocol as a helper for the HTTPS proxy.

Comment: ... Ok so the problem here is that _MY_ firewall allows essentially nothing out ... it allows FTP, telnet, Http (through a proxy) and a few other common ones. essentially ports in [20,29] and a few other ones... how can i whois a server _outside_ ...? i tried whois -h whois.arin.net 80 as well as one of those on the ip-adress.com proxy list 80 and I don't believe they work ...

Comment: Whois (RFC3912) runs on top of TCP, not on top of HTTP, so there is no concept of proxies in this protocol. You need to use the standard methods of lower levels like IP tunnels, port redirections, SOCKS library, etc. Or use an HTTP wrapper provided by some service.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is probably to use a third-party HTTP whois service such as http://whois.domaintools.com/ and then scrape the results from the generated web page.  The WhoisXmlAPI is also HTTP-based I believe; http://www.whoisxmlapi.com/whoisserver/WhoisService?domainName=example.com

Comment: problem. we're talking about some series queries, probably >1000 easily. I'm pretty sure they will be unhappy.

Comment: Au contraire, they'll be happy to take you on as a paying customer.  With that kind of volume, you'd be running up against query limits no matter what you use so the proxy isn't really a major factor here.

Comment: .... when you're working in a nonprofit and don't have money to pay them ........

Comment: If USD 15 is too much, try to convince them to give you a rebate or a free ride.  Both domaintools.com and whoisxmlapi.com have free, limited developer accounts, too.

Comment: [jsonwhoisapi.com](https://jsonwhoisapi.com) offer 1000 free parsed WHOIS lookups per month so worth a look into i guess

Comment: @EiyrioüvonKauyf can you explain your use case, for a nonprofit organization that needs to do > 1000 whois queries?

Comment: I'm not @EiyrioüvonKauyf but there are many organizations -- academic, commercial, govermental, and NGO -- who want to do data mining experiments and thus need bulk data to even get started exploring an idea.